# Can Windows XP run on Raspberry pi?

Tags: windows

I would like to run a windows xp OS on my raspberry.
If I try to install it with Win32DiskImager would be able to use?
Which version should I try?

Comment: Do you know the minimum requirements for Window's XP?  If the Pi meets the minimum requirements you will be able to run XP.

Comment: its really a terrible idea

Comment: Even if you could run Win XP it is beyond end of life.

Comment: Someone got windows 98 to run on the raspberry. Looks like a proof of concept more than a useful thing- https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7016/qemu-virtual-machine-win-98-disk-error

Comment: @MatthewMartin no they didn't. They got a QEMU (probably) emulated VM to run windows 98.

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to tell someone else not to help someone just because you differ in opinion. Joan is completely right that you can in fact run XP on an ARM device through virtualization.

Comment: Face palm, shaking head...

Comment: It will not run on latest python 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not done research.

The minimum requirements for Windows XP are (from Microsoft Knowledge Base):

- Pentium 233-megahertz (MHz) processor or faster (300 MHz is recommended)
- At least 64 megabytes (MB) of RAM (128 MB is recommended)
- At least 1.5 gigabytes (GB) of available space on the hard disk
- Video adapter and monitor with Super VGA (800 x 600)or higher resolution
- Sound card

Raspberry Pi does not meet those requirements, due to the fact that the maximum Raspberry Pi specifications are (from Wikipedia):

[image]

So, to answer your question: **no**, you can't.

And please do more research in the future. Do a Google search for `Can I run Windows XP on Raspberry Pi`, you'll find many topics and answers to them, with the answer: no.

Comment: You seem to have pasted the requirements twice. Also, I seem to remember running Windows XP in 8-bit VGA mode, like 320x240x8, so it at least does support such resolutions. Maybe plain VGA card would be enough.

Comment: STOP UPVOTING THIS! This is only slightly nearer the answer than the one on the Potato SE website, someone asked if their potato could run windows XP and (I think it was the same guy) posted the XP minimum specifications and said "Even the most advanced potato doesn't match these" - It cannot run, it's not because it's a bad computer, it's because it's an ARM CHIP!

Comment: @AlecTeal Not necessarily. If it had a better processor, it wouldn't work either.

Comment: Read it again...

Comment: Yeah, this answer is puzzling to me too. The OP says that the rPi doesn't have enough requirements, lists XP requirements then lists the Pi's. The XP requirements are much lower than what the Pi has. 

The only thing questionable is possibly the video/sound support. Not that it would be worth it, but it might be entirely possible to run a VM XP on Pi. Don't know if it would be worth it or even feasible but don't care. 

I'm just pointing out the obvious flaw in this answer. And asking the not-so-obvious question, why doesn't it meet the requirements?

Comment: P.S. I've seen Mac OSX Mavericks run on an ARM device using QEMU. So, again.. not sure why the rPi can't VM XP.

Comment: This answer is just wrong.  The reason you cannot run Windows XP on the pi is because Windows XP has not been compiled for the particular architecture.  If it were, it could be used.  But since the source code is not available, no one can legally do it.

Comment: @goldilocks You're forgetting about virtualization. Additionally, there are licenses you can purchase to virtualize Windows on other platforms legally. Mac OSX wasn't compiled for ARM either but low and behold, it runs flawlessly on my HDMI stick.

Comment: @LeviRoberts Good points. There is a related question here about using an x86 simulator: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/can-i-emulate-x86-to-run-windows-95 I still think this answer misses the point, however.  By "no one can legally do it", I meant, compile windows for armv6, not that there might not be some other legit method.  I'm sure Microsoft would not care about someone using Windows on the pi, but they would if you somehow copped their proprietary source code in order to do so.

Answer (score 24):

**TL;DR Yes it is possible to virtualize Windows XP on an ARM device such as Raspberry Pi.**

For anyone saying that this isn't possible needs to re-evaluate what "possible" means. Just because it hasn't been done yet (which it has), it's not appropriate to say it's impossible. In fact, it's generally never a good idea to claim something as impossible.

That said, it IS entirely possible to run x86 systems on an ARM device if it meets the standard requirements. I have first hand experience with getting `Mac OS X Mavericks` running on an ARM HDMI stick, primarily aimed at running Android on a TV. This setup requires that [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) be compiled and running with a specific configuration.

There are also guides that have ported `Windows 95`, `98`, `XP` and other x86 system to run on many ARM devices.

One such guide can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1459153)

From the guide:

```
 Now you can run x86 based operating systems on your ARM device. 
 Now you can have full desktop windows/linux experience on your Android smartphones.
```

It should be noted that this guide was primarily written with an Android operating system in mind, however one with enough experience can get a minimal `Linux OS` running on the rPI, say [Debian](https://www.debian.org), [Linux Mint](https://www.linuxmint.com) or [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) and then attempt to get `QEMU` compiled.

Looking at the minimum system requirements of Windows XP and then comparing those to Raspberry Pi's specifications, at a glance I would say it's possible to virtualize XP. I don't know what kind of performance you could get and it might even prove to be unusable. However, it would be an interesting experiment to try.

To give you an idea of the steps that would be required, it would look something like this.

1. Get a linux distribution of your choice to run on RPI, like Debian, Ubuntu, etc.
2. Compile QEMU with whatever requirements that Windows XP needs to emulate. This step requires research on your part.
3. Virtualize Windows XP with a running version of QEMU and attach the video to the QEMU instance.
4. Most things in the OS should operate normally, however you may run into compatibility problems with hardware due to emulated conditions.
5. Note the limitations of running Windows XP, which is a very dated piece of software that has reached it's end of life. This means that newer modern web browsers, firewalls, anti-virus solutions and many more key pieces of software probably won't run properly, if it all.

**Extras:**

Here is a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrq_VtrnhHE) of how to get QEMU running on the Pi.

Here are some reasons of why I think it could be possible.

- A YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0GL66m5HY4) in German that displays Windows XP booting up in 20-some minutes on a Raspberry Pi.
- Eye witness accounts of running OSX Mavericks on an Android HDMI stick
- Several tutorials of running past OS's with QEMU virtualization (x86 to ARM)

Comment: To the down voter: Care to leave a comment on what or why you disagree with this answer? Your negative feedback provides no value in this instance. I have an idea of whom this came from and why. That's what happens when not everyone agrees.

Answer (score 17):

The answer is no. The Raspberry Pi is powered by an ARM processor, and there is no ARM Windows version

Comment: This - seriously.

Comment: There are several Window's versions which run on ARM processors.

Comment: @joan *Windows.

Comment: @william-david-edwards Not sure what you are suggesting.

Comment: @joan It's Windows, not Window's ;)

Comment: I was looking for this, everyone else is trying to compare minimum specs when windows xp wont even run on a arm chip :P

Answer (score 10):

You couldn't directly run Windows XP but you might be able to put it through an emulator. The only problem is that it would really slow.

Comment: Or this. This is why.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not interested in running Windows XP in particular, but I'm running an x86 Debian userland on my Pi 4, which allows [running](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/121497/33476) Windows programs via Wine.

The performance is certainly worse compared to running native ARM code, but it's not that bad. Here's a test with Exagear emulator:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 i686 GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=1000 run
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark
...
Test execution summary:
    total time:                          7.5422s
```

Compared with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=1000 run
sysbench 0.4.12:  multi-threaded system evaluation benchmark
...
Test execution summary:
    total time:                          3.5249s
```

The performance gap becomes more apparent if the program in question tries to use hardware acceleration, e.g. the emulated x86 version of `gltron` only gives me about 10 fps, while the ARM version runs fine with 50+ fps.

Comment: Yes, depends very much on what software you run and if it's full system emulation or the qemu userland translation layer as then kernel calls will be native.

Comment: @onion It's userland translation layer (note the kernel is `v7l` in both runs), not that it matters that much in a number crunching test. I just wanted to provide some performance numbers, as there are lots of answers / comments claiming that the emulation will be "very" or "prohibitively" slow where it is in fact acceptable in many cases.