# Run Windows XP in qemu on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: windows, pi-2, qemu

It's possible to run Windows XP in qemu on Raspberry Pi 2? 
Loading Windows XP would be very slow?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23010/can-windows-xp-run-on-raspberry-pi I think most of the facts discussed there would still apply. While the Pi2 provides more computational power it still is the same architecture.

Comment: I am however not sure this should be closed as dupe. Maybe somebody tried and found the 4 cores sufficient ;) (However unlikely that might be).

Comment: just use win 2000 and 98 works fine so does 95

Answer (score 1):

That other question referenced by Ghanima includes an answer which refers to  a youtube video showing Windows XP boot in QEMU on a non-2 model (they all have the same processor, GPU; the A/A+ has less RAM).  That video [is still around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0GL66m5HY4) and it does seem that it takes **20+ minutes** for XP to boot.<sup>1</sup>

If there were a native version for the pi, it would be much quicker; hardware emulators slow things down drastically.  They are intended more for use in development than to deliver a nice end-user experience, and of course there is no point in developing x86 Windows XP software on a Raspberry Pi unless you are some kind of masochist.

So, the pi 2 has been described as 6 times faster than the previous versions.  Figures contrasting multicore to single core execution times are a bit idealized in that they will only apply to certain situations.  I haven't done any benchmarks but I'd say when doing general purpose things that can be multi-threaded to some extent, the Pi 2 is 3-4 times faster (with an ARMv7 userland).

But let's assume 6 times.

```
21.5 / 6 = ~3.6
```

*So you might be able to boot Windows XP in under 4 minutes!*  In reality I think it will be more, presuming XP doesn't really exploit multiple cores much in boot (maybe it does, I'm just guessing).

The only way to find out for sure is to try...but I think you are going to be very disappointed.

---

<sup>1. I left that video running while writing this and after 17 minutes, still no taskbar.  Exciting stuff.</sup>

Comment: "Exiting stuff" ;) Booting in under four minutes. Pretty close to a Pentium I 133 Mhz... (Ok, maybe nobody would have run XP on that either).