# Cannot install Wine from Pi-apps

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, emulation, pi-apps

I'm trying to install Wine on a 32-bit Raspbian using [Pi-Apps](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps). I have already successfully installed Box86 emulator from the same place. However, Wine installation ends in a segfault:

```
Installing Wine (x86) with install-32 script
Your system is using a 3G/1G kernel. Continuing...
Running pkg-install...
Waiting until APT locks are released... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
output: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
cabextract is already the newest version (1.9-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
No new packages to install. Nothing to do!
--2021-02-27 17:34:38--  https://twisteros.com/wine.tgz
Resolving twisteros.com (twisteros.com)... 185.199.108.153, 185.199.109.153, 185.199.110.153, ...
Connecting to twisteros.com (twisteros.com)|185.199.108.153|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 67938781 (65M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘/home/pi/wine.tgz’

/home/pi/wine.tgz                       100%[=============================================================================>]  64.79M  15.4MB/s    in 4.3s    

2021-02-27 17:34:44 (15.2 MB/s) - ‘/home/pi/wine.tgz’ saved [67938781/67938781]

--2021-02-27 17:36:32--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.110.133, 185.199.109.133, 185.199.111.133, ...
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.110.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 879667 (859K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/usr/local/bin/winetricks’

/usr/local/bin/winetricks               100%[=============================================================================>] 859.05K  3.53MB/s    in 0.2s    

2021-02-27 17:36:32 (3.53 MB/s) - ‘/usr/local/bin/winetricks’ saved [879667/879667]

Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 db176ad3 built on Feb 15 2021 00:05:11
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 db176ad3 built on Feb 15 2021 00:05:11
Box86 with Dynarec v0.2.1 db176ad3 built on Feb 15 2021 00:05:11
008c:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event
008c:err:clipboard:convert_selection Timed out waiting for SelectionNotify event
00b8:err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
00b8:fixme:dwmapi:DwmIsCompositionEnabled 6D95DD14
00c0:fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyIpInterfaceChange (family 0, callback 0x6a0df537, context 0xe29060, init_notify 0, handle 0x166fce8): stub
00b8:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
wine: configuration in L"E:\\home\\pi\\.wine" has been updated.
First wineboot finished. Now updating wine prefix...
/usr/local/bin/wine: line 2:  8256 Segmentation fault      setarch linux32 -L /home/pi/wine/bin/wine "$@"

Installed Wine (x86) successfully.

Closing in 30 seconds.
```

Subsequent calls to `wine` also result in a segfault:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ winecfg
/usr/local/bin/wine: line 2: 15171 Segmentation fault      setarch linux32 -L /home/pi/wine/bin/wine "$@"
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wine explorer
/usr/local/bin/wine: line 2: 15174 Segmentation fault      setarch linux32 -L /home/pi/wine/bin/wine "$@"
```

Any ideas what might be wrong? Box86 is working as far as I can tell. I tried reinstalling both Wine and Box86, rebooting, and wiping the `~/.wine` folder before installation.

Comment: Why not log an issue on PiApps GitHub? https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps/issues

Comment: @CoderMike I've already contacted the author on Discord, trying a bunch of suggestions right now. Of course I'll open an issue if the problem will be confirmed. I think it's still useful to have the question here, not many people know they can install Wine on a Pi in the first place.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Are you sure this is supposed to work? On https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian it says: "Raspbian users: the WineHQ packages are for x86 architecture only; they cannot be installed on an ARM system."

Comment: @PMF, check out [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118263/33476) for instance. It's indeed possible to run x86 code under an emulator on an ARM kernel. I'm interested in testing this emulator in particular, to compare the performance

Comment: Ok, sounds interesting, indeed. I thought you were trying the other way round (installing Box86 under wine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some [troubleshooting](https://github.com/Botspot/pi-apps/issues/400) the issue was identified: `Wine (x86)` fails to run if there are other handlers for x86 ELF files than Box86. The solution is to remove other emulators (QEMU, Exagear, etc.) from the system.

As a side note, Wine + Box86 are amazingly fast, for instance, StarCraft and Heroes of Might and Magic 2 run full speed on a Pi 4. Many games will still fail to run at this point, but Box86 being an open-source project (and quite recent) makes me believe the situation will improve with time.